# Creating intellisense in a editor - how? tips?

Tags: java, grails, intellisense, code-completion

I Need to create a smart address editor. I would like to add something like intellisense.

In my country, Colombia, addresses usually have words like "Calle (Street)", "Carrera", "Avenida (Avenue)", "Conjunto (Set)", "Interior", "Transversal" as well as names. The idea is to enable the user to enter addresses follow a standard. There are several standards, but it is generally Abbreviations: CL, CR, AV, CJ, IN, TV, etc.

I found this interesting article on the subject:

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Code_Completion_Design

But it is in C and I do think it does not require such complexity. In my case there are only about 60 special words that the editor should detect and translate the standard. There are no parameters, packages, etc. Is simpler.

I also think that an API or framework as well, can have many applications or uses in other contexts.

Anyone know some code in Java or Grails?. An API? Can you give me some tips or ideas? Thank you very much in advance.

Edit:
I just found another tutorial that promises much:
http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-completion.html

Comment: Can you explain with what standards you want the user to insert the names ?

Comment: Thanks, for example, the user enter 'Avenida' , or 'Avda', or just 'Av'. The editor should to  show a list with 'Avenida (AV)' and to translate this selection a 'AV'.

Comment: Finally, I took the code found on this page: http://laktek.com/2011/03/03/introducing-jquery-smart-autocomplete/. It was exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you would gain doing this on the server side.

I would look at some of the javascript autocomplete functionality ( such as jQuery UI's http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ ) to try to do this on the client side. You would have to tweak it so that it doesn't replace the entire string, but the ideas are very similar.